# Trigger to prevent UPDATE and convert it into INSERT

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I have an entity which can be attached to other entities.
I want to prevent any updates to this, instead can have new entries.
That way I can keep existing links intact, and add new entries

There is a status column (active/inactive)
When an update is issued, I want to update only status of the row to inactive.
And then insert the updated values as new row.
Would appreciate if this can be done in a generic way, which would work for all tables, and we will just need to add the trigger calling a function.

Something like

```
create  trigger prevent_update_trigger
   before update on the_table
   for each row execute procedure prevent_update_do_insert();

create or replace function prevent_update_do_insert() 
returns trigger as 
$$ 
begin 

    // Code to update it to INACTIVE

    -- Insert the UPDATE row as new row

    // Code to INSERT new row

    -- do NOT proceed with original UPDATE
    return null;
end;
$$ 
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: What is wrong with the [answer you accepted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/242742/1822) on dba.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I couldnt complete my requirement from there, thats the reason @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: And I thought of re asking here, to get more eyes maybe.